# nullPointerException when calling sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I am new to Spring. When I'm trying to view [localhost:8080/persons](http://localhost:8080/persons), I am getting an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null 
at by.bsuir.task.service.PersonServiceImpl.listPersons(PersonServiceImpl.java:32) ~[classes/:na] 
at by.bsuir.task.controller.PersonController.listPersons(PersonController.java:31) ~[classes/:na] 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na] 
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE] 
at ...
```

I think problem is in PersonDAOImpl, method listPersons(), `session` getting NPE. But I'm not sure.
My project below:

> PersonServiceImpl

```
package by.bsuir.task.service; 

import java.util.List; 

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; 

import by.bsuir.task.dao.PersonDAO; 
import by.bsuir.task.model.Person; 

"personService" 
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService { 

private PersonDAO personDAO; 

public void setPersonDAO(PersonDAO personDAO) { 
this.personDAO = personDAO; 
} 

@Transactional 
public void addPerson(Person p) { 
this.personDAO.addPerson(p); 
} 

@Transactional 
public void updatePerson(Person p) { 
this.personDAO.updatePerson(p); 
} 

@Transactional 
public List<Person> listPersons() { 
return this.personDAO.listPersons(); 
} 

@Transactional 
public Person getPersonById(int id) { 
return this.personDAO.getPersonById(id); 
} 

@Transactional 
public void removePerson(int id) { 
this.personDAO.removePerson(id); 
} 

}
```

> PersonDAOImpl

```
package by.bsuir.task.dao; 

import java.util.List; 

import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory; 
import org.slf4j.Logger; 
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository; 

import by.bsuir.task.model.Person; 

@Repository 
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO { 

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class); 

private SessionFactory sessionFactory; 

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){ 
this.sessionFactory = sf; 
} 

public void addPerson(Person p) { 
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
session.persist(p); 
logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p); 
} 

public void updatePerson(Person p) { 
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
session.update(p); 
logger.info("Person updated successfully, Person Details="+p); 
} 

"unchecked" 
public List<Person> listPersons() { 
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
List<Person> personsList = session.createQuery("from Person").list(); 
for(Person p : personsList){ 
logger.info("Person List::"+p); 
} 
return personsList; 
} 

public Person getPersonById(int id) { 
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id)); 
logger.info("Person loaded successfully, Person details="+p); 
return p; 
} 

public void removePerson(int id) { 
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id)); 
if(null != p){ 
session.delete(p); 
} 
logger.info("Person deleted successfully, person details="+p); 
} 

}
```

> PersonController

```
package by.bsuir.task.controller; 

import java.util.List; 

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
import org.springframework.ui.Model; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod; 

import by.bsuir.task.model.Person; 
import by.bsuir.task.service.PersonService; 

@Controller 
public class PersonController { 

@Autowired 
private PersonService personService; 

required=true 
@Qualifier(value = "personService") 
public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){ 
this.personService = ps; 
} 

value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET 
public String listPersons(Model model) { 
List<Person> listOfUsers = this.personService.listPersons(); 
model.addAttribute("person", new Person()); 
model.addAttribute("listPersons", listOfUsers); 
return "person"; 
} 

//For add and update person both 
value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST 
public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p){ 

if(p.getId() == 0){ 
//new person, add it 
this.personService.addPerson(p); 
}else{ 
//existing person, call update 
this.personService.updatePerson(p); 
} 

return "redirect:/persons"; 

} 

"/remove/{id}" 
public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id){ 

this.personService.removePerson(id); 
return "redirect:/persons"; 
} 

"/edit/{id}" 
public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){ 
model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id)); 
model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
return "person"; 
} 

}
```

Cannot seem to find what my problem is, I'm just learning about Spring\Hibernate

Comment: Seems like your personDAO member variable in PersonServiceImpl is null.

Comment: You didn't mark your setter as `@Autowired`, so Spring is not handling it. For mandatory dependencies, use constructor parameters instead of setters, and in this case, Spring Data JPA can replace your entire DAO setup with a one-line interface declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some code in your question.

For the class `PersonServiceImpl`, the code should be as follows:

```
@Service("personService") 
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService { 

    @Autowired     
    private PersonDAO personDAO; 
    // Some other code
}
```

Add `@Autowired` annotation to the `PersonDAO` class without doing so will result in `NullPointerException` as you did not create any object for that class, annotating it with `@Autowired` will tell the Spring where an injection needs to occur.

Comment: The OP does need `@Autowired`, but field injection is discouraged. Constructor injection is the way to go here.

Comment: Exception is the same, but stack trace now is a little bit other: `java.lang.NullPointerException: null 
at by.bsuir.task.dao.PersonDAOImpl.listPersons(PersonDAOImpl.java:38) ~[classes/:na] 
at by.bsuir.task.dao.PersonDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ed6750f0.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na] 
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE] 
at ... `